# Conflicts during install in empty env

Tags: conda

I've create new environment

```
(jh2) [xxx@yyy~]$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /opt/miniconda
jh2                   *  /opt/miniconda/envs/jh2
```

And it's obviously empty

```
(jh2) [xxx@yyy~]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /opt/miniconda/envs/jh2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

I have offline channel on filesystem

```
(jh2) [xxx@yyy~]$ conda config --get channels
--add channels 'file://opt/repo/repository_conda-forge/jh_offline/'   # lowest priority
```

but when I try install some package, it fails.

```
(jh2) [xxx@yyy~]$ conda install jupyterhub=1.0.0 --offline
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package tornado conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> tornado[version='>=5.0']
Package async_generator conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> async_generator[version='>=1.8']
Package jinja2 conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> jinja2
Package traitlets conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> traitlets[version='>=4.3.2']
Package python-dateutil conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> python-dateutil
Package configurable-http-proxy conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> configurable-http-proxy
Package certipy conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> certipy[version='>=0.1.2']
Package sqlalchemy conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> sqlalchemy[version='>=1.1']
Package entrypoints conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> entrypoints
Package pamela conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> pamela
Package pycurl conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> pycurl
Package python conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
Package alembic conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> alembic
Package requests conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> requests
Package oauthlib conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> oauthlib[version='>=3.0']
Package prometheus_client conflicts for:
jupyterhub=1.0.0 -> prometheus_client[version='>=0.0.21']
```

I don't understand how can I have conflicts in empty env !

On top of that. On machine with internet access exactly same packages are installed without any problem.

When I e.g. try `conda search tornado` the package is availiable

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
tornado                        6.0.3  py36h516909a_0  repo/repository_conda-forge/jh_offline
tornado                        6.0.3  py37h516909a_0  repo/repository_conda-forge/jh_offline
tornado                        6.0.3  py38h516909a_0  repo/repository_conda-forge/jh_offline
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Are all of those packages available in your offline channel?